# Timeout in Calabash tests

Tags: cucumber, calabash, calabash-ios

I have updated the calabash gem to the latest `version(0.20.0)` and tried to run the tests on `iOS 10` devices. The issue I am facing is that the first test executes as expected but the consecutive tests are failing with the following error message:

```
Timed out after 60.04 seconds executing

 with a timeout of 60
   (RunLoop::Shell::TimeoutError)
```

I get the following warning message on the console, however I am not sure if these are related with the issue.

```
WARN: 
Calabash::Cucumber::Launcher #calabash_no_launch? and support for the NO_LAUNCH
environment variable has been removed from Calabash.  This always returns
true.  Please remove this method call from your hooks.

WARN: The server version is not compatible with gem version.
Please update your server.
https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios/wiki/Updating-your-Calabash-iOS-version
       gem version: '0.20.0'
min server version: '0.20.0'
    server version: '0.19.1'
```

Could you please share your thoughts on this issue.

Comment: The warnings are explicit.  Don't use NO_LAUNCH.  Stop using it.  You need to update your server.  Please give more information! What is timing out???

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to to a 'bundle exec calabash-ios download' again so you can download the latest version of the Calabash server that matches what you have installed which is 0.20.0 and then rebuild your app in Xcode with that framework added. Then use that version for testing.  Or, if your build server is doing the work, you just need to update the gem on your build server and rebuild.

Comment: The link in the error message says everything you need to know to fix the issue: https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios/wiki/Updating-your-Calabash-iOS-version